# Identifying oscillation in a time series

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I asked this on the mathematics site, but now I think this is a better place.  Sorry for the cross-post.

Given any line graph, is there a reliable way to identify any sort of regular oscillation?

Let's assume I'm charting the prevalence of different species of animals in a single location, over the span of several years. What sort of algorithm could I apply that would identify a regular migration instead of a steady increase or decline?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked at Fourier methods?

Answer (score 6):

You may want to look at spectral analysis techniques. Look at,
[Shumway & Stoffer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144197864X) (among many other books which treat the subject) or look "Spectral analysis" in the Wikipedia for some pointers.

Comment: I would also add Larry Bretthorst's book on spectral analysis to your reference. can be downloaded for free [here](http://bayes.wustl.edu/glb/book.pdf).

Comment: @probabilityislogic: Thank you, I have used that book in paper, good to know that it is freely available in electronic form.

Answer (score 2):

[Noether's Test for Cyclic Trend](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-21/issue-2/Asymptotic-Properties-of-the-Wald-Wolfowitz-Test-of-Randomness/10.1214/aoms/1177729841.full) may help. You'll find this routine implemented in the [IMSL Statistical libraries](https://web.archive.org/web/20110909041110/http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/c-library/docs/7.0/Cstat.pdf) which are accessible from a variety of programming languages.

The book *Modeling Hydrologic Change: Statistical Methods* by Richard H. McCuen, covers Noether's Test as well as multiple others that you'll likely find useful. The book is available as a [pdf file here](http://www.ce.metu.edu.tr/%7Ece530/Modeling%20Hydrologic%20Change_Statistical%20Methods.pdf) (warning, it is big).